# Apache Fortress TLS

Tags: maven, tomcat, ldap

I am new in ldap enviromnet and I am trying to set up the apache fortress with symas openldap (https://github.com/apache/directory-fortress-core/blob/master/README-QUICKSTART-SLAPD.md)

When I set up with ldap, all the integration tests pass succesfully but when I set the ldaps it throws an handshake error.

Does someone now where I have to set all the client and server certificates because setting up as the repository README, it is not possible.

**Fixed:**

Following the below answer of the creator of that project, I got the proper set up with LDAPS.

**Next Problem:**

But now I get an error when I run the 3rd step of Apache Fortress Rest Set Up:

`mvn clean install -Dload.file=./src/main/resources/FortressRestServerPolicy.xml tomcat:deploy`

**error output:**

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:deploy (default-cli) on project fortress-rest: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Error writing to server -> [Help 1]`

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-1:deploy (default-cli) on project fortress-rest: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager`

`Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager`

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server`

I set up in tomcat the roles and users *manager-gui* (which I am able to access through http and https, hostname/manager/html) and *manager-script*

Changing tomcat maven plugin in pom.xml, I could deploy:

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

but after I get that error...

`FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/fortress-rest] but context failed to start`
Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TLS or LDAPS for the connection to the LDAP server does not require a client-side certificate.  You will need to create a server-side cert for the LDAP host, and add that to the OpenLDAP configuration.  You also must add that server's CA certificate to the Java truststore on the client-side, i.e. the fortress runtime.

For a tutorial on how to accomplish this, checkout [the Apache Fortress Demo](https://github.com/shawnmckinney/apache-fortress-demo). (Note that I am the author of this demo.)

This tutorial's scope goes beyond just creating and using certificates.  The specific steps you're going to be interested in are:

- http://shawnmckinney.github.io/apache-fortress-demo/apidocs/doc-files/keys.html
- http://shawnmckinney.github.io/apache-fortress-demo/apidocs/doc-files/hosts.html
- http://shawnmckinney.github.io/apache-fortress-demo/apidocs/doc-files/openldap-ssl.html
- http://shawnmckinney.github.io/apache-fortress-demo/apidocs/doc-files/apache-fortress-core-ssl.html

Comment: Hi Shawn! Thanks for contributing your knowledge to Stack Overflow. Note that, in order to avoid spam and other such things, we have [a policy requiring that authors disclose their affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when recommending products/services that they are affiliated with. It doesn't need to be anything complicated; I've added that disclosure to this answer. Please keep this in mind for the future.